# Convert NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to convert my `NSDictionary` (storageData) to an `NSArray`, as I need to pass the data (title) contained in the dictionary through a segue. I've implemented the below (see last method, the tableview is simply to provide some context), but a crash occurs with the following error:

> *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance*

Any idea how to fix?

**Viewcontrolller.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

        {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            NSDictionary *tmp = [self.storageData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(long)indexPath.row]];

        [[cell itemName] setText:(NSString *)[tmp objectForKey:@"title"]];

              NSString *title = [tmp objectForKey:@"title"];
              [[cell itemName] setText:title];

 NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[node objectForKey:@"body"]];

NSString *secondLink = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"];

[cell.itemPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

              }

              return cell;
              }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *values = [self.storageData allKeys];

    ItemDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ItemDetailViewController alloc]
                                                                   initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.title = [[values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    detailViewController.itemDetail = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.secondLink = self.descripData[indexPath.row][@"photo"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
       }
```

Comment: It's hard to guess about your data structure, but you can find out what's wrong by using `NSLog()` to show the class of each object you send a `objectForKey` message to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you would extract allValues instead of allKeys then you could only:

```
[values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Since you are using a index as indexPath.row. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I implemented the above line, and the crash stopped. However when I changed allKeys to allValues, I got this crash: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]:

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you are calling objectForKey in an object of type NSString, which doesn't have that method declared.

So put a breakpoint in the beginning of the method, step over each line one by one until crashes and then check what is the variable that you are thinking is a Dictionary when it is a String.

Comment: This is the line that's giving me issues: detailViewController.title = [[values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]; I assume that's because title is an NSString. When I NSLog values, it shows my data.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Treating this as a dictionary: %@", [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] );`